# .NET Core POST request trouble with many-to-many relationship in Web API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm making Web API in .NET Core, using EntityFrameworkCore. I'm trying to write a POST request to table, that implements many-to-many relationship it looks like this:

```
public class Agency
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public IList<Book> Books { get; set; }
    }

public class Author
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public IList<Book> Books { get; set; }
    }

public class Book
    {
        public Guid AgencyId { get; set; }
        public Guid AuthorId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Language { get; set; }   
        public int Pages { get; set; }

        public Agency Agency { get; set; }
        public Author Author { get; set; }
    }

public class DataContext : DbContext
    {
        public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options) 
            : base(options) { }

        public DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Agency> Agencies { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Author> Authors { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Book>().HasKey(b => new { b.AgencyId, b.AuthorId});

            modelBuilder.Entity<Book>()
                .HasOne<Agency>(b => b.Agency)
                .WithMany(a => a.Books)
                .HasForeignKey(b => b.AgencyId);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Book>()
                .HasOne<Author>(b => b.Author)
                .WithMany(a => a.Books)
                .HasForeignKey(b => b.AuthorId);
        }
    }
```

I wrote a repository and a wrapper for it, it works OK, but I have trouble on POST for Book entity:

```
public IActionResult Post(Book model)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest("Invalid data.");
            }

            var book = new Book();
            book.Title = model.Title;
            book.Language = model.Language;
            book.Pages = model.Pages;
            book.Author = _repoWrapper.Author.FindByCondition(a => a.Id == model.AuthorId).FirstOrDefault();
            book.Agency = _repoWrapper.Agency.FindByCondition(a => a.Id == model.AgencyId).FirstOrDefault();

            _repoWrapper.Book.Create(book);
            _repoWrapper.Save();
            return Ok();
        }
```

When I make this request, I get data duplication exception. What I need to change to make it work right?

Answer (score 0):

If the exception occurs during the Save method, make sure that the `AgencyId` and `AuthorId` of your newly added Book data will not be duplicated with the previous data at the same time.

Because you set `the primary key of the combination of AgencyId and AuthorId` to the Books table in OnModelCreating.